# problem with expo-image-picker: TypeError: ImagePicker.requestMediaLibraryPermissi onsAsync is not a function

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I have a functions to take a picture from the cell phone library, when I run the code the following warning is display:

[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: ImagePicker.requestMediaLibraryPermissionsAsync is not a function. (In 'ImagePicker.requestMediaLibraryPermissionsAsync()', 'ImagePicker.requestMediaLibraryPermissionsAsync' is undefined)]

Here are my import

`import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker';`

And here are the function:

```
    const pickImage = async () => {
        let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
            mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
            allowsEditing: true,
            aspect: [3, 4],
            quality: 1,
        });

        if (!result.cancelled) {
            setImage(result.uri);
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was having the same issue but I find that the correct documentation for the SDK version I'm using.

In my case was changing the function to `ImagePicker.getCameraRollPermissionsAsync()`.

Here's a link to the expo's [image picker documentation](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/v39.0.0/sdk/imagepicker/) and you can select your version at the top on the left-hand side menu.